# Eclipse build command does not have necessary permissions on Ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to build an Android project in Eclipse on Ubuntu.  The project is using cocos2dx, but that's almost incidental to the issue at hand.

Basically, to build with cocos, I need to set the build command in my project's C/C++ settings to a file called build_native.sh.  This calls the ndk-build executable in my android-ndk directory.

The problem is, this process appears to have a step that requires changing file permissions, which Eclipse cannot do with it's current permissions.  I get the following console output:

```
make: Entering directory `/media/sdb1/Dropbox/Documents/Code/Eclipse/ColorsWS/ColorsGame'
Install        : libcocos2dcpp.so => libs/armeabi/libcocos2dcpp.so
install: preserving times for `./libs/armeabi/libcocos2dcpp.so': Operation not permitted
make: Leaving directory `/media/sdb1/Dropbox/Documents/Code/Eclipse/ColorsWS/ColorsGame'
install: setting permissions for `./libs/armeabi/libcocos2dcpp.so': Operation not permitted
```

When I run build_native.sh with sudo, it works and I get the proper library.  I can refresh the project directory in Eclipse to get Eclipse to notice this file, but Eclipse still believes there's an error.  What should I do?

Comment: You should never run these commands with sudo; first because they aren't security vetted for that, second because once you do, you leave behind build products, temporary files, and/or lock files owned by root - which your normal user account can't cleanup or replace.

Comment: Interesting. Good to know. Luckily this is the only time I've done that so the damage should be minimal. Unfortunately my issue still stands

Comment: You can probably as root do a recursive `chown` of the project or workspace trees to your normal account.

Comment: Would that be safer?  I tried chown on certain files and as far as I could tell I didn't even successfully own them afterwards.  I'll try again tonight doing it recursively and post my results.

Comment: More a generic unix help problem, but you need to run chown as root/with sudo.

Comment: Yes. I knew that and I did that. I'll try again and if it doesn't work I'll be sure to clearly explain what I did here.

Comment: The answer, as it always seems to be, was rather silly.  The problem was that I was saving my files on a mounted filesystem, instead of in the home directory.  I assumed this was okay because I was used to Windows, but for one reason or another on Ubuntu I cannot change the ownership of files in a mounted system.